# Show "loading..." message until get the coordinate

Tags: javascript, html

Here I already have the script to get the coordinate (Latitude & Longitude). Since, when I clicked the button, some people wonder when the coordinate will come up. So, how to show the `loading...` until the coordinate is shown in the input text without reloading the page.

Here is the code:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("lati");
var y = document.getElementById("longi");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
  y.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
  document.getElementById("input_latitude").value = x.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("input_longitude").value = y.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div class="mb-3"><input class="border rounded-0 form-control" type="text" name="business_latitude" id="input_latitude" placeholder="Latitude" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" value="<?php echo $business_latitude; ?>" required></div>
<div class="mb-3"><input class="border rounded-0 form-control" type="text" name="business_longitude" id="input_longitude" placeholder="Longitude" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" value="<?php echo $business_longitude; ?>" required></div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" onclick="getLocation()">Current Location</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You just need to show "loading...." and hide it when you paste the Geolocation.

Comment: Duplicate of "[How to add text "Please wait a while..." on clicking the button in JavaScript function](//stackoverflow.com/q/68112043/90527)" and many, many others. Some keywords: "placeholder", "loading", "indicator", "busy", "text"; "asynchronous", "while waiting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work. I have added a `<p>` tag which doesn't have text in it by default. When the user clicks on the button, I paste "loading..." inside the `<p>` tag and when the result is shown I change it back to blank.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("lati");
var y = document.getElementById("longi");

function getLocation() {
  document.getElementById("loadingText").innerHTML = "loading...";
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    document.getElementById("loadingText").innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    document.getElementById("loadingText").innerHTML = "";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
  y.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
  document.getElementById("input_latitude").value = x.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("input_longitude").value = y.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
#loadingText {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="mb-3"><input class="border rounded-0 form-control" type="text" name="business_latitude" id="input_latitude" placeholder="Latitude" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" value="<?php echo $business_latitude; ?>" required></div>
<div class="mb-3"><input class="border rounded-0 form-control" type="text" name="business_longitude" id="input_longitude" placeholder="Longitude" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" value="<?php echo $business_longitude; ?>" required></div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" onclick="getLocation()">Current Location</button>
  <p id="loadingText"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may be useful to the OP, providing [additional context](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/90527) regarding why & how it works, and when it should be used will improve its long-term value by helping other readers.

Comment: @outis I do explain but I was in a bit of a hurry when I answered the question. I will add it now.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var x = document.getElementById("lati");
var y = document.getElementById("longi");

function getLocation() {
  document.getElementById("input_latitude").value = "Loading...";
  document.getElementById("input_longitude").value = "Loading...";
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, () => {console.log("Error")});
  } else { 
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  console.log(position);
  x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
  y.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
  document.getElementById("input_latitude").value = x.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("input_longitude").value = y.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="lati"></div>
<div id="longi"></div>
<div class="mb-3"><input class="border rounded-0 form-control" type="text" name="business_latitude" id="input_latitude" placeholder="Latitude" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" value="<?php echo $business_latitude; ?>" required></div>
<div class="mb-3"><input class="border rounded-0 form-control" type="text" name="business_longitude" id="input_longitude" placeholder="Longitude" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" value="<?php echo $business_longitude; ?>" required></div>
<div class="mb-3">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" onclick="getLocation()">Current Location</button>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may be useful to the OP, providing [additional context](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/90527) regarding why & how it works, and when it should be used will improve its long-term value by helping other readers.

Comment: The code above has a flaw... If the function fails, it shows that your browser doesn't support geolocation, but it will still keep showing "Loading...".

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById("lati");
var y = document.getElementById("longi");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
     document.getElementById("input_latitude").value = "Loading...";
     document.getElementById("input_longitude").value = "Loading...";
     document.querySelectors('input').setAttribute("disabled");
     //input is disabled so that input can not be edited.
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, () => 
     {console.log("Error")});
  } else { 
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  console.log(position);
  x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
  y.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
  document.getElementById("input_latitude").value = x.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("input_longitude").value = y.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: While this code may be useful to the OP, providing [additional context](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/90527) regarding why & how it works, and when it should be used will improve its long-term value by helping other readers.